# Change color iron-icon when tapped

Tags: javascript, css, polymer

I have a [very basic example](http://jsbin.com/kaqeyub/edit?html,console,output) where I want to change the color of a iron-icon when it's tapped.

I use iron-selector for the tapping:

```
<template>

<style>

  :host {
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
    --iron-icon-fill-color: blue;
  };

  .iron-selected iron-icon {
    --iron-icon-fill-color: red;
  };

  .iron-selected iron-icon {
    fill: purple;
  }

</style>

<iron-meta id=meta key="info" value="some"></iron-meta>

<iron-meta id=meta key="sub">
  <a href="some"></a>
</iron-meta>

<iron-selector id="one" selected="0">
  <div><iron-icon icon="android" class="ico"></iron-icon></div>
  <div><iron-icon icon="menu" class="ico"></iron-icon></div>
</iron-selector>


</template>
```

I was told before that this is a limitation of the shim, where only one custom value per element-scope can be kept.

Writing a "straight" selector (see the change in "pink") actually works.

Now... if I wanted to use the variables provided by the component (`--iron-icon-fill-color`) rather than manipulating the CSS directly, what would I need to write? (or, is it actually impossible?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE:** The newly released [Polymer 1.6.0](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/releases/tag/v1.6.0) supports native CSS properties (no shim), so your code would work without `updateStyles()`.

To enable native CSS properties, initialize the `Polymer` variable before importing `polymer.html`:

```
<script>Polymer = {lazyRegister: true, useNativeCSSProperties: true};</script>
```

```js
HTMLImports.whenReady(_ => {
  "use strict";

  Polymer({
    is: 'x-foo'
  });
});
```

```html
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+1.6.0/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Enable native CSS properties (instead of shim) -->
  <script>Polymer = {lazyRegister: true, useNativeCSSProperties: true};</script>
  <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">

  <link rel="import" href="iron-selector/iron-selector.html">
  <link rel="import" href="iron-icons/iron-icons.html">
</head>

<body>
  <x-foo></x-foo>

  <dom-module id="x-foo">
    <template>
      <style>
        :host{
         --iron-icon-fill-color: blue;
        }
        .iron-selected {
          background: #eee;
        }
        .iron-selected iron-icon {
          --iron-icon-fill-color: pink;
        }
      </style>

      <iron-selector selected="0">
        <div>
          <iron-icon icon="android" class="ico"></iron-icon>
        </div>
        <div>
          <iron-icon icon="menu" class="ico"></iron-icon>
        </div>
      </iron-selector>
    </template>
  </dom-module>
</body>
```

[codepen](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/pbPBZB?editors=1010)

---

From Polymer 1.5.0 [docs](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/styling#style-api) (emphasis mine):

> Polymer's custom property shim evaluates and applies custom property values **once at element creation time**.

Since you're updating the style with a custom property dynamically (i.e., after element creation), the custom property would have to be reapplied by calling [`updateStyles()`](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/api/Polymer.Base#method-updateStyles). You could listen to the `<iron-selector>`'s [`iron-select`](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-selector#event-iron-select) event to trigger this update.

```
// template
<iron-selector on-iron-select="_updateStyles">

// script
Polymer({
  ...
  _updateStyles: function() {
    this.updateStyles();
  }
});
```

```js
HTMLImports.whenReady(_ => {
  "use strict";

  Polymer({
    is: 'x-foo',
    _updateStyles: function() {
      this.updateStyles();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+1.5.0/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
  <link rel="import" href="iron-selector/iron-selector.html">
  <link rel="import" href="iron-icons/iron-icons.html">
</head>

<body>
  <x-foo></x-foo>

  <dom-module id="x-foo">
    <template>
      <style>
        :host{
         --iron-icon-fill-color: blue;
        }
        .iron-selected {
          background: #eee;
        }
        .iron-selected iron-icon {
          --iron-icon-fill-color: pink;
        }
      </style>

      <iron-selector selected="0" on-iron-select="_updateStyles">
        <div>
          <iron-icon icon="android" class="ico"></iron-icon>
        </div>
        <div>
          <iron-icon icon="menu" class="ico"></iron-icon>
        </div>
      </iron-selector>
    </template>
  </dom-module>
</body>
```

[codepen](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/mEmoBP?editors=1010)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<iron-icon on-tap='updateColor'></iron-icon>
```

And js

```
updateColor:function(){
 this.customStyle['--iron-icon-fill-color']='blue';
 this.updateStyles();
}
```

You can read more about it [here](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/styling#style-api).

This might change the color of all the `iron-icons` in a `dom`, so i recommend assigning a new variable for the icon you want to change color of and then changing its value instead of `--iron-icon-fill-color`.

```
:host{
 --my-custom-property:pink;
}
.icon{
 --iron-icon-fill-color:var(--my-custom-property,pink);
}
```